# Python problem when sending emails to different recipients

Tags: python, email, sendmail

I want my program to send an email to different people, depending on what data a website is displaying.

Example:

#I define this first
msg['to'] = 0

while count < 5:
global msg['to'] #The problem is that this is not a correct way to make it global

```
if something = something:
  msg['to'] = "john@gmail.com"
  #and do stuff to send the email
else:
  print ("something")

if something = something:
  msg['to'] = "elon@gmail.com"
  #and do stuff to send the email
else:
  print ("something")
```

How can I change msg['to'] to a global variable and change it inside the code to different emails, depending on what data a website is displaying?
PS! doing "global msg" in the beginning does not fix the issue.

Comment: I think there's only one `to` field and you need to put semi-colons `;` between the names.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I modify the msg['To'] field, so I can change the email recipients in my code as shown?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so it's hard to give you advice.  Normally a dictionary is mutable, so if you pass it into a function as a parameter you can make changes to it.

Comment: Solution:`def sendMail(recipients, content):
   msg = EmailMessage()
   msg['Subject'] = ''
   msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
   msg['To'] = recipients
   msg.set_content(content)
   with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
      smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
      smtp.send_message(msg)`

Comment: So `msg['To']` accepts a list or tuple?  Excellent!